# Toggle only this item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, slidetoggle

i've a problem to toggle only (this) 1 'card'

```js
$('a[rel="toggle_comments"]').click(function(){
        
  var div = $('.comments');
  $(div, this).slideToggle('slow');
        
});
```

```html
<!-- This is a example code -->

<section>
  <div class="mainclass">
    [...]
    <div class="select">
      <a href="#" rel="toggle_comments">Test</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <ul class="comments">
    <!-- Content -->  
  </ul>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="mainclass">
    [...]
    <div class="select">
      <a href="#" rel="toggle_comments">Test</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <ul class="comments">
    <!-- Content -->  
  </ul>
</section>

[...]
```

When I clicked at 'toggle_comments', toggle all '.comments' classes, not only that, I have clicked. Anyone have any ideas?

Sorry for my bad english.
I hope you understand what I mean - Thanks :-)

Comment: Do you mean that you wish to toggle only the `.comments` under the `<section>` tag that the link is in?

Comment: To toggle all, do `div.slideToggle('slow');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to toggle only the `.comments` under the `<section>` tag your link is in, do this:

```
$('a[rel="toggle_comments"]').click(function(){
  // find the closest section tag (parent) and find all child `.comments`
  var $comments = $(this).closest('section').find('.comments');
  $comments.slideToggle('slow'); 
});
```

If you want to toggle all `.comments`:

```
$('a[rel="toggle_comments"]').click(function(){
  $('.comments').slideToggle('slow'); 
});
```